# HTTP File Upload via Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, internet-explorer

I try to upload a file automatically via powershell on a Fritz!Box but it doesn't work.
I log on to it via the internet explorer.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("192.168.178.1/")
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
$ie.document.getElementById("uiPass").value = "pass"
$ie.Document.getElementById("submitLoginBtn").click()
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy)) 
$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName['uiImport'].value=Get-Content "myfile" -Raw
```

My problem is, I really don't get what the property has to be for the uiImport. This is where my file should get uploaded in a form but Powershell keeps saying that it can't find this property.

Answer (score 0):

> $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName['uiImport'].value=Get-Content
>   "myfile" -Raw

Please try to use F12 developer tools to check the web page resource, whether the page contains the "uiImport" custom tag.

From my point of view, I think perhaps "uiImport" is the input elements **Name** attribute, instead of tag name. If that is the case, you could use the **Document.getElementsByName()** method to find the input text. Then, set the value.

Sample code as below:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("<web page url>")
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))

$elements = $ie.document.getElementsByName("files")
$elements[0].value ="file path"
```

The web page resource:

```
Upload file : <input type="text" id="txtupload" name="files" class="file"  value=""/><br />

Download file : <input type="text" id="txtdownload" name="files" class="file" value=""/>
```

In above sample, I was using the index to find the special upload text, you could also where clause or using the Document.getElementById() method to find the text box. Code as below:

```
$uploadtext = $ie.document.getElementsByName("files") | ?{ $_.Id -eq 'txtupload'}
$uploadtext.value ="hello world"
$downloadtext = $ie.document.getElementsByName("files") | where{ $_.Id -eq 'txtdownload'}
$downloadtext.value ="hi"
```